# Why are self-undeleted posts not shown in the 10k tools?

Tags: discussion, support, 10k-tools, undelete

I can understand not dragging self-deleted content into the spotlight. If there were problems with it, it's deleted anyway and they don't matter now, and the OP probably had their own private reasons for deleting it. Nothing wrong with self-deleting answers if you know they're bad.

But why are self-undeletions not shown? Seems like it'd be pretty easy to abuse; it's the only way to (re-) introduce posts to the site without anyone noticing. I can think of two scenarios off the top of my head:

- A frustrated user abusing the moderators. Downvotes and flags start to roll in? Simply delete it to dismiss the flags on it and undelete later. I've actually seen this one happen before, but it was re-deleted fairly quickly because it was still on the front page.
- A spam bot specifically designed for Stack Exchange. Post spam to a high-view question, immediately delete it, undelete it after a week or two when nobody's going to notice.

Is there a specific reason for not showing these posts to 10k users?

Comment: Moderators do have a list of self-deleted posts.

Comment: @kiamlaluno So by extension a list of self-undeletions as well? I suppose that mitigates the abuse potential somewhat, given that moderators actually review that list. But I still can't think of a valid reason for hiding them from 10kers.

Comment: As far as I can see, that page still reports posts that have been un-deleted. I cannot find any reason for hiding that information to 10k users, except that is information that is normally not necessary to 10k users.